# Why collection.get() is not working in Firestore?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm working with the following collection and sub-collections in Firestore.

[image]

I need to retrieve the list of the documents inside "Schedine", but the following code returns nothing.

```js
const ref1 = await firestore.collection("Schedine").get();

ref1.forEach(doc => {
  console.log(doc.id);
});

// expected output: gx8qiytV8Zgs0AJR4swFqTH3T82 , but nothing shown
```

Instead, if I try to `get()` the documents inside "in corso", a sub-collection of a document inside "Schedine", it works, with the exact same code:

```js
const ref2 = await firestore.collection("Schedine").doc("gx8qiytV8Zgs0AJR4swFqTH3T822").collection("in corso").get();

ref2.forEach(doc => {
  console.log(doc.id);
});

// WORKING
```

How could I get the list of the documents inside "Schedine"?

Answer (score 2):

If you look carefully, you'll see that the document ID in your screenshot is shown in italics. This means that there's no document `gx8qiytV8Zgs0AJR4swFqTH3T822` inside your `Schedine` collection, and the console just shows that ID so that it can show you the subcollections under it.

Since there's no documents in `Schedine`, calling `get` on that collection returns an empty query snapshot. But the *path* exists, which is why you can access the subcollection once you *know* the document ID in your second snippet.

There's no API on the collection reference to get such non-existent entities, so the common solution is to create an (empty) document when you also create the subcollection.